# How to auto adjust dt dd width in css?

Tags: html, css, dt, dd

I use dt and dd to create a paper form.

dt width should match the word and dl should match remain space

Now I adjust each line manually, how can I use css to auto do this?

```css
div {
  width: 200px;
}


/* dl dt dd same line */

dl {
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0
}

dt {
  float: left;
  /* adjust the width; make sure the total of both is 100% */
  padding: 0;
}

dd {
  float: left;
  /* adjust the width; make sure the total of both is 100% */
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}

dl dt:nth-of-type(1) {
  width: 36%;
}

dl dd:nth-of-type(1) {
  width: 64%;
}

dl dt:nth-of-type(2) {
  width: 26%;
}

dl dd:nth-of-type(2) {
  width: 74%;
}

dl dt:nth-of-type(3) {
  width: 14%;
}

dl dd:nth-of-type(3) {
  width: 86%;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <dl>
    <dt>aaabbbccc:</dt>
    <dd>&nbsp;</dd>
    <dt>aaabbb:</dt>
    <dd>&nbsp;</dd>
    <dt>aaa:</dt>
    <dd>&nbsp;</dd>
  </dl>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Semantically, a `ul` makes more sense for what you're presenting. In your example, the `dd` is being targeted purely for layout, yet it contains no relevant definition content. Using a `flex` display on the `li`, we can target an empty italics element to draw the remainder of the bottom border underline, however long it needs to be.

```css
ul, li {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

div {
   width: 200px; 
}

div li {
  display: flex;
}

div li i {
  border-bottom: 1px solid;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <ul>
    <li><span>aaabbbccc:</span><i></i></li>
    <li><span>aaabbb:</span><i></i></li>
    <li><span>aaa:</span><i></i></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7f3x8bw2/)

Comment: I agree with your suggestion of using flex but dd is not purely for layout, semantically it is for defining a grouping of definitions with associated titles/headings. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/dl

Comment: @Calummm I'm not saying `dd` is inherently for layout. I'm saying it's not being used properly. This—`<dd>&nbsp;</dd>`—is not an adequate definition list description.

Comment: Thank you for adding the clarification, that makes more sense now.

Comment: It works for me, I'm not the question author though